# Angular material datepicker don't select the date that I choose

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

Angular material datepicker don't select the date that I choose insteadI always get the sysdate in the angularjs controller even if I select another date. What I'm doing wrong?

My controller:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'growl',
        'modalService', 'moment',
        '$uibModal', '$log', 
        function ($scope, growl, modalService, 
                moment, $uibModal, $log) {

                                $scope.initDate = new Date();

                                $scope.printDate = function() {
                                    console.log($scope.initDate);
                                }
        }]);
```

my view

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="initDate" md-placeholder="Select a date"
           ng-change="printDate()"
           md-min-date="minDate"
           md-date-filter="disabledWeekned">
         </md-datepicker>
```

Comment: Seems okay - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/KgWdWw?editors=1010#0

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try to apply your datepicker with a model if you can:

```
$scope.model = {};
$scope.model.initDate = new Date();

<md-datepicker ng-model="model.initDate" md-placeholder="Select a date"
       ng-change="printDate()"
       md-min-date="minDate"
       md-date-filter="disabledWeekned">
     </md-datepicker>
```

Hope it helps =)